# Координаты префаба со сцены в скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

скрипт респавна объекта

```
    public class spawnItems : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public float SpawnTime=4.0f;
    public GameObject StealthMush;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnMush",SpawnTime,SpawnTime);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void Stop() { CancelInvoke("SpawnMush"); }
    public void SpawnMush()
    {
        int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0,SpawnPoints.Length);

        Instantiate (StealthMush,SpawnPoints[spawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints[spawnIndex].rotation);
    }
}
```

скрипт взаимодействия с некоторыми предметами

```
public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;
    public Transform mushrums;
    public Transform mushrumsInv;
    public Transform fastRun;
    public Transform beastFear;
    private Animator anim;
    GameObject closest;
    public GameObject invisibility_btn;
    public GameObject fastRun_btn;
    public GameObject fear_btn;
    public spawnItems stoprepeat;

    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }
    GameObject FindClosestEnemy() {
        GameObject[] gos;
        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("mushrums");
        //GameObject closest;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance) {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }
    public void HandUp () {
        float dist =  Vector2.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
        float distInv = Vector2.Distance(player.position, mushrumsInv.position);
        float distRun = Vector2.Distance(player.position, fastRun.position);
        float distFear = Vector2.Distance(player.position, beastFear.position);
        Debug.Log(mushrums.position);
        Debug.Log(mushrumsInv.position);
        Debug.Log(distRun);
        Debug.Log(distFear);
        if (dist <= 59.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("PickUp");
            Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
        };
        if (distInv <= 21.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("PickUp");
            stoprepeat.Stop();
            Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
            invisibility_btn.SetActive(true);
        };
        if (distRun <= 5.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("PickUp");
            //Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
            fastRun_btn.SetActive(true);
        };
        if (distFear <= 21.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("PickUp");
            fear_btn.SetActive(true);
        };

    }

}
```

как грамотно перенести координаты объекта из инстанса скрипта респавна на объект mushrumsInv скрипта взаимодействия?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько. Все зависит от того, где еще могут быть нужны эти координаты и на сколько они уникальны.
Можно сделать статическую переменную и передавать через нее.
Можно использовать систему сообщений.
Можете искать на сцене нужный GameObject, а в нем GetComponent<название_скрипта>().название_переменной.

"Грамотно" это вещь относительная. Лучше отталкиваться от архитектуры, которую вы закладываете и какие шаблоны проектирования уже используете.

Я, признаюсь, не до конца понял логику в вашем коде, было бы хорошо, чтобы вы вычленили из него саму суть, касающуюся вопроса, но вы можете попробовать один из предлагаемых мной вариантов.